# Got `Source Code does not match bytecode` debug a Reversed Android app

Tags: disassembly, debugging, android

Reverse an `.apk` file following [This Article](https://blog.netspi.com/attacking-android-applications-with-debuggers/)

1. Open `ApkStudio`, edit `AndroidManifest.xml` to allow debug and Build a new Apk file
2. Got source code with `dex2jar` and `jd-gui`
3. Create an project in `Android Studio`
4. Put source code into the project folder
5. install the apk in an Emulator
6. run the app and start `Attach Debugger` in Android Studio

Breakpoints successfully reached, but got no debug information with a `Source Code does not match bytecode` warning.

What's wrong with my operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code you got is not a perfect match, it is representative.  You will likely want to debug in [smali](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali), not Java. The smali plugin for AndroidStudio works really well for this.